# Async function waits for async global variable but returns Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

Considering the example below, I would expect the `test` function to wait 1 second (which it actually does) and then print the right message. However, it returns a `Promise`.

```
function wait (ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => { resolve(`Successfully waited ${ms} ms`) }, ms)
  })
}

const asyncVar = wait(1000)

async function test () {
  console.log('Starting test function..')
  await asyncVar
  console.log(`Done waiting ${asyncVar}`) // => [object Promise]
}

test()
```

However, in the second snippet example below, if declaring a new variable from within `test` function it will display the right value.

```
function wait (ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => { resolve(`Successfully waited ${ms} ms`) }, ms)
  })
}

const asyncVar = wait(1000)

async function test () {
  console.log('Starting test function..')
  let _asyncVar = await asyncVar
  console.log(`Done waiting ${_asyncVar}`) // => Successfully waited 1000 ms
}

test()
```

What is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Because that's how it works. `asyncVar` is always a promise. When you `await` it, you get a value. If you put `await` in front of `asyncVar` - it doesn't transform or mutate `asyncVar` - it's still a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async function test () {
  console.log('Starting test function..')
  await asyncVar
  console.log(`Done waiting ${asyncVar}`) // => [object Promise]
}
```

In this code, ${asyncVar} is a promise because you are just calling the variable outside again this one "const asyncVar = wait(1000)", and at that moment it is not resolved yet. If you write this below you will achieve desired results:

```js
function wait (ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => { resolve(`Successfully waited ${ms} ms`) }, ms)
  })
}

const asyncVar = wait(1000)

async function test () {
  console.log('Starting test function..')
  await asyncVar
  console.log(`Done waiting ${await asyncVar}`) 
}

test()
```

`await` will hold that line until the promise gets resolved or rejected.